# Why is google listing HTTP 405 pages in the "Indexing Errors/Other" section of Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

I have subpages used for AJAX which allow only HTTP POST and return HTTP 405 "Method Not Allowed" on other request types. I believe is the correct response code in that case.

Google recently indexed my website and now in Google Search Console displays all of the mentioned subpages in "Indexing Errors/Other" section.

1. Should I be worried about those "Indexing errors"? Will this influence in any way my search engine position?
2. Should I attempt to fix these errors? If yes what can be done? My server includes `X-Robots-Tag:noindex, noodp, noarchive` in the 405 response headers, however this seems to be ignored.

Comment: I just edited your title because from your question it is clear that Google is NOT indexing these pages.   It sees the 405 error code which *prevents* it from indexing the content.  It then subsequently lists these pages as "crawl errors."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to fix here.  You don't want Googlebot crawling and indexing those URLs.   Google is reporting that it tried crawling them, but got an error.

Fix errors that happen on pages that have content you want indexed.  If Googlebot got 405 errors on normal pages, that would be a problem.

These crawl errors are expected.  You have set it up in such a way that any visitor or bot that fetches the URL with a GET will see an appropriate error.  That is all that has happened:  Google got an appropriate error and listed in the appropriate report.

Crawl errors on non-content URLs don't hurt your site in any way.  Google expects to encounter 404 errors when crawling healthy sites.  They have even said that a million non-content 404 errors in that report won't adversely effect your site.  The same goes for other errors.  If it is on a page that doesn't have indexable content, there is no need to worry about Googlebot encountering it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to allow the use of the GET method on that subdirectory.  HEAD would also be safe.